# Signalr not calling client-side javascript functions in IIS 8

Tags: iis, signalr

I CURRENTLY have a signalr web app, hosted in IIS 8.5. My app works fine locally but when it's hosted in IIS webserver, the signalr hub isn't able to make any calls back to the client.

Using fiddler, I found the following exception after calling:

```
The connection to '' failed. 
Error: TimedOut (0x274c). 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

It's making a `get` request to the wrong ip address and port, which isn't my website address.

I'm using webSockets.

Javascript code:

```
 function backEndFactory(serverUrl, hubName) {
    var connection = $.hubConnection("localhost");
    connection.logging = true;
    var proxy = connection.createHubProxy(hubName);

    connection.start({ transport: ['webSockets'] }).done(function () { });

    return {
        // signal r server call this callback
        on: function (eventName, callback) {
            proxy.on(eventName, function (result) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        // call the client function passing in the return data from the server
                        callback(result);
                    }
                });
            })
        },

        //  call signal r server function
        invoke: function (methodName, callback) {
            proxy.invoke(methodName).done(function (result) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        // return data after calling method in signal r server
                        callback(result);
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    }
}


var dashboardHub = proxy(serverUrl, hubName);
        dashboardHub.on("ClientsUpdateBirthdays", function (data) {
            $scope.birthdays = data;
        });
```